# Make *.crt *.pem certificates available inside Azure App service running on docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, docker, ssl

## Context

I'm using Azure App service to run a node.js application that should connect to MongoDB using SSL. The app deployed with a docker container. MongoDB server and node.js MongoDB client requires to use `*.pem` and `*.crt` certificates.

## Problem

Azure web app services (TLS/SSL settings) does not allow me to upload self-signed certificates with `*.pem` and `*.crt` file extension. Only `*.pfx` extension is allowed.

How I can make `*.pem` or `*.crt` files available inside the container? Are there other ways to connect node.js app with MongoDB using SSL in Azure?

Comment: do you have the private key? Are you looking at binding the cert at the webapp layer or internal application layer?

Comment: @Bevan Yes, I have the private key? Sorry, don't understand what you mean by webapp/interna/cert level.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you have the provate key just use openSSL to create a PFX file. Once your PFX file is created you can simply upload to your Azure WebApp. An even better approach is to upload into an Azure KeyVault then import to your WebApp/App Service Plan

I use this command to prepare my certificates for use in Azure

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out PFXCertName -inkey PrivteKeyFile -in PEMCertificateFile -passout pass:PrivateKeyPassword
```

I create this little script for command shell to prompt for the values. Just save it as `.bat` and run

```
@Echo off

set /P Cert=Enter Cert Name (Including Extension):
set /P CertKey=Enter Cert KEY Name (Including Extension):
set /P PFX=Enter New PFX Cert Name to Output (Including Extension):
set /P Password=Enter New PFX Password (Including Extension):

Echo Creating the PFX certificate

openssl pkcs12 -export -out %PFX% -inkey %CertKey% -in %Cert% -passout pass:"%Password%"
```

Comment: Will SSL connection between a MongoDB server and a Node.JS client work with *.pfx certificates? From documentation In documentations they are using *.pem certificates https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/ssl/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/configure-ssl/

Comment: The reference to Azure web app services in the original question confused me. My answer allows you to upload the pfx file to the webapp (Azure resource). If you want the files in the container, can you edit the dockerfile to copy the certificate files into the image during the build?

Comment: Yeah, putting certs into the image is an option, but this is not secure. Appreciate your help, Bevan!

Comment: If you want to bind the cert to an application in the image, the certificates will need to be part of the image. If the azure webapp resource is the endpoint, you can upload the certs to the webapp and bind them to a hostname in the portal.

Comment: I'm an Ops guy, not a developer so I don't know how this is handled in the application (I assumed the App just reads the Env variable), HOWEVER, I : 
- Upload/Import the certificate to App Service
- Deploy App Service with Application Setting named "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" with the value of the certificate thumbprint. For our config this is also a self-signed certificate and enables secure resource to resource communication.

Comment: We use Sitecore and this is how it handles the App Service cert. Implementation will be a little different for you but the concept is the same. Remove the need to include the crt in your Build : https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/replace-a-sitecore-client-certificate-in-azure.html